# How do I get the following SQL statement to work and return a join while picking one string?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, A and B. Table A has an id and a string, and table B has a pointer to an id in A and a number (float).

I want to select everything from table B, averaging the number as group by id in table A, while also showing the string from table A.

This doesn't work:

```
 select a.id,b.id,avg(num),str from a,b where a.id=b.id;
```

It gives me an error about grouping str.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You should really show some sample input and output, as your question could be open to interpretation.

Comment: What is a pointer in SQL? Did you mean a foreign key? And -1 for describing the error without showing the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you use an aggregate function, like avg(), you have to group the results that are not already grouped

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, avg(num), a.str FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.id, a.str;
```

That's basically it.  Except that you also need to clarify which table "str" comes from.  Is it a or b?
(Answer updated as per comment.)

Comment: str is coming from table A.

Answer (score -1):

Use `group by` clause To use aggregate functions you have to use `group by`

```
select a.id,b.id,avg(num),a.str from a,b where a.id=b.id group by a.id
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This will still cause the same error, because the other columns are not part of the group.